# Start React App with Command Line Arguments

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to be able to launch my client-side React app from another programming language and pass it some command line arguments which would be passed to top level props or a context (or whatever).

I basically want to be able to launch a command like:

```
npm start inputFile="/path/to/input/file.ext"
```

And have the inputFile path be passed to my React app.  Is this possible?  I'm using `create-react-app` to bootstrap my app.

Comment: [Victor C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13145936) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67057573) saying "Check documentation: [https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) there u can find exemples"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

declare them before the command,
`INPUT_FILE="/path/to/input/file.ext" ANOTHER_INPUT_FILE="/another/path/to/input/file.ext" npm start`

accessible via `process.env.INPUT_FILE`
oh the convention is usually uppercase and separated by underscore between words.

or more convenient if you can just put them in .env file
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#expanding-environment-variables-in-env